# Opendkim running but not signing?

Tags: sendmail, opendkim

I have had a lot of fun with OpenDKIM - it is actively running on my Debian box and here is my code:

```
root@web1:~# tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep -i dkim
Sep  7 16:35:38 web1 sm-mta[1504]: 087FZbYw001504: Milter insert (1): header: DKIM-Signature:  v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=simple/simple;\n\td=web1.mydomain.com; s=web1; t=1599492938;\n\tbh=+j1V4TFBmUGM3frMlslpv/49yjR0n44tuVimZHHRn0Q=;\n\th=Date:To:From:Reply-To:Subject:From;\n\tb=Z1gNvmXGQZXdx3iXGDpAWsdROt8iBctCrf248LQWtpNq5D3803fEWgUWCo9Bi81Bx\n\t qpE3hKokZTfD3jHlmyuhV9kZMulxEVv+jcjBXaK5r2L4957mUYW4Ao+UgBycqM6jt9\n\t CuOE+YStbaWal5mNNtf0NplJCHbHYk25NTV1y2zs=
```

However when I test the signature using https://www.appmaildev.com/en/dkim I am getting `DKIM-Result: permerror (no key)`

From the result of the tail I believe Opendkim isn't being passed the necessary to,from,reply-to etc but thats just my guess. Why would the email not be signed?

This is my /etc/opendkim.conf but I'm unclear where I would see any extra details such as the "LogWhy" should generate.

```
Syslog                  yes
UMask                   007
Socket                  inet:8891@localhost
PidFile               /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid
OversignHeaders         From
TrustAnchorFile       /usr/share/dns/root.key
UserID                opendkim
Domain                web1.mydomain.com
KeyFile               /etc/opendkim/web1.private
Selector              web1
LogWhy                  yes
```

So to be clear - my question is: **Why is the email not being signed with DKIM?**

`TXT record` for corresponding domain (`dig TXT web1._domainkey.mydomain.com`):

`web1._domainkey.mydomain.com. 1799 IN TXT "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDNa5dPxaE/o8nwuYd8H+qN2zfxC+5H4Y6iHCYFd0mhMLyy3fMOUoR5rEccu+cDDtv1OP9r3ko17c5K+nKenxghYbZKoRQfZu+OO6qKz+Q5PODSpWlfugXJDBDcwxcNM+k8A4zXwohBFFddpZINZ7nAnpqNqYLxrEjutwpIfjbZIwIDAQAB"`

MXtoolbox reports for web1 and mydomain.com the records are setup correctly.

Line added to sendmail.mc
`INPUT_MAIL_FILTER(`opendkim', `S=inet:8891@localhost')`

Comment: Just running a dkim service is not enough. Did you configure your MTA to actually use it?

Comment: Did you configure your DNS with the DKIM key? The message looks like the email is signed correctly but the key could not be validated from the DNS.

Comment: Yes I set the Sendmail parameters as required - the SOCKET variable and masquerade as

Comment: If there is any way I could debug it further I'd appreciate any direction.

Comment: Show the `TXT` record you created in DNS for it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in fact that I was running on a subdomain but testing against the full domain when running `dig`.

The full command *should* have been:

`dig TXT web1._domainkey.web1.mydomain.com @8.8.8.8`

Which would have shown there was no key and required a discussion with my IPS to check what had gone wrong.